# What does it mean by this sentence: He is confronted in his subzero lab by.....?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/synopsis)

> He is confronted in his subzero lab by Roy and Leon, **the latter of
>   whom rips open Chew's thermal coat** to make it easier for Roy to
>   interrogate him.

What does it mean by this highlighted sentence?

Answer (score 1):

"the latter of whom" is a relative construction that refers back to the second-mentioned of the two people, "Leon".  You can think of "the latter of whom" as a proxy for the noun "Leon".  We use "whom" because people are involved. The same construction can be used with things, in which case we use "which" instead of "whom".

> The medicine cabinet contained a bottle of aspirin and some ipecac,
>   **the latter of which** induces vomiting.

Answer (score 1):

The *former* of two things, is the first-mentioned.

The *latter* of two things, is the last mentioned.

The *former* of Roy and Leon is Roy. The *latter* of Roy and Leon is Leon.

"whom" is a pronoun that refers to the pair of people, Roy and Leon.

So, in this case, "the latter of whom" refers to Leon and "the former of whom" would refer to Roy.